# Como controlar o tamanho das células em uma tabela HTML?

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando controlar o tamanho de uma célula da minha tabela HTML utilizando as propriedades de CSS `height` e `width`, porém não está funcionando.

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
#CelL7C1, #CelL3C1, #CelL3C3, #CelL7C3{
    height: 5px;
    width:20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow);
}
```

Comment: Cara vc tem que colocar a sua tabela inteira ai não só um pedaço de CSS, sem um modelo mínimo para poder simular seu problema não da para te ajudar ...

Comment: Posta seu html da tabela, só com isso não da pra ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pra fazer isso precisa especificar um tamanho fixo de largura na `table` e depois determinar o que precisa no `td` tipo:

```
table {
    max-width: 90px;
}
td {
    width: 25px;
}
```